# How to read .awz ebooks on Macbook Pro (Mac OS X 10.6.8)?

Tags: ebook, kindle

How to read .awz ebooks (Kindle format) on Macbook Pro (Mac OS X 10.6.8)?

Can it be converted to PDF with hyperlinks properly supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to read a Kindle ebook on your Mac is to download [Amazon's application for that purpose](http://www.amazon.com/kindleformac/) (either from their site or the Mac App Store). As **Thilo** points out in the comments, however, a DRMed Kindle title can only be read on the device which downloaded it, so moving the `.azw` to your Mac won't help. Instead, assuming this is a book you acquired from Amazon's store, you can download another copy and have it sent to the Kindle app on your Mac.

As for converting to PDF, `.azw` files are DRM-protected [Mobipocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobipocket) files. Assuming you can remove the DRM [somehow](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/), there are many resources online that can do `.mobi -> PDF` conversion.

Comment: +1. If they do have DRM, they will be tied to a certain device, however, so Kindle for Mac will not open them, either. If this is something you bought from Amazon, you can re-download it and select "Send to Kindle on my Mac".

Comment: @Thilo Good point - I've updated my answer to include that info. Thanks!